# Disable inputs with jquery by default

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to disable by default the inputs, and i have a check box that allows to enable them;
so my code of the checkbox is :

```
function toggleStatus() {
  if ($('#toggleElement').is(':checked')) {
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('disabled', true);
  } 
  else {
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
}
```

and it's called in an input with `onchange="toggleStatus()";` but the default status of the inputs are enabled and i don't want to add disabled="disabled" to each input, how can i do it with jquery? and how can i make it work with the existing onchange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Disable the inputs when the DOM is ready.

**O.K. After your update**, the answer is even simpler, just trigger the `onchange` event:

Either with:

```
toggleStatus();
```

or with

```
$('#toggleElement').change();
```

Comment: if i want to do "if ($('#toggleElement').is(':checked')) {" to be unchecked, how i do it ? like i'm ready to type check

Comment: i did: if ($('#toggleElement').change()) {
but not working, i set the checkbox to be unchecked and the fields are disabled now i want when i click on the check box to enable them, like an opposit of my is(':checked') thing. thanks a lot for the help @gdoron

Comment: @Abude. Who told you to write it inside of an `if`...? just `$('#toggleElement').change();`

Comment: i can't make it work how exactly should it be, sorry because I'm troubling you

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').prop('disabled', true);
});


function toggleStatus() {
      if ($('#toggleElement').is(':checked')) {
          $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('#elementsToOperateOn :input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
</script>
`

Comment: @Abude. I need the markup as well. Produce a DEMO please in the link above.

Comment: don't know how to use jsperf, the html is like this :
 <form method="POST">
 <input id="toggleElement" type="checkbox" name="toggle"  onchange="toggleStatus()"/>
    <table class='table' id='elementsToOperateOn'  >
<input>...
</form>

Comment: thanks a lot @gdoron, i just reverted the if conditions, thanks a lot for all the help. appreciate it !

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr`:

```
$(':input').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input, select').not('#toggleElement').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Do you know what `.not` does?

Comment: Yes. It removes the checkbox from the jQuery set. If you disable every input field you cannot undisable them by clicking the checkbox. Well... if I understood the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

have jquery go through each input field on startup and add the disabled attribute

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input').each(function(){

      $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

      });
    });
```

for your toggle script, use a class selector

```
$('.elementsToOperatOn').each(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: It's not necessary to loop through just to set properties using jQuery.

Comment: I wanted to say the same thing as @saluce, and explain why, buy you can just see the other answers. Sorry for being lazy. :